# Is breaking something an irreversible change?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

The science textbooks say that, unlike change of state, not all physical changes are reversible. For this, the example provided is grinding wood into sawdust or tearing off paper. They say that we cannot recover paper from its pieces again. However, I think we can. To make it simpler, consider the example of ice. If I break the ice, it is a physical change. In this case, I can melt the pieces and freeze the water again to recover the ice. Hence, this becomes a reversible physical change. I argue that the same goes for the tearing of a paper, too. However, I wonder if, in the process of recovery, we are allowed to use any method, physical or chemical.

My purpose is not to get to the right definitions or examples of physical or chemical change but to understand why we have to call some changes reversible and some irreversible while we can reverse, in my understanding, all physical changes. I wonder if the same is true for chemical changes as well.

Comment: If you tear off paper, you may recover paper from its pieces using some chemical solution to dissolve cellulose, and reproduce paper again. But the breaking operation has not been really reversed. Furthermore the obtained recovered paper will not look like original paper. It will not contain the same cellulose molecules at the same place. Also the ink and dyes deposited on the previous paper will not be reproduced.

Comment: There is several meanings of reversibility, in different contexts. 1/Being in equilibrium during state changes 2/ Being able to revert the process/change  3/ Being able to revert the process/change by reverting the state of the neighborhood. // For 3/, if you use fuel to melt the ice and then freeze it, the neighborhood changed, so it is not reversible process by 3/ even if the phase change itself can be reversible by 1/ and 2. // Or if freezing/melting is too fast, it may be reversible by 2/ and 3/ in other scenario, but not by 1/.

Comment: Personally, I'd avoid thinking about it too much. This sort of definition is not really watertight and the more you look into it, the more problems you're going to find. Reversibility has a formal definition in thermodynamics, but it's not the same as what you've been taught (it's something you see in a more advanced chemistry course), and it also doesn't have any link to the classification of something as a physical or chemical change.

Answer (score 3):

Some physical changes *are* reversible, if the requirement is simply that materials are *substantially similar* at beginning and end. Here are two examples.

- Crush a salt crystal, dissolve it in water, and let the water evaporate. *Substantially* the same crystal structure results. However, it would be somewhat ;-) unlikely that each atom of the first crystal returned to the same position in the second. We'd still say the process was reversible.
- Boil water, and then condense it. Again, the end-product substantially resembles the starting material.

Some physical changes *are not* reversible, if the requirement is that *long range order* in materials are identical at beginning and end. Here are two examples.

- If one were to cut *Guernica* in Museo Reina Sofía into slices in a paper shredder, there is no technique to restore Picasso's work to be the exact original. [The reasonable person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reasonable_person), looking at the results of an attempted restoration, would say it is *not* the original.
- Look at a piece of wood. Note the whorls and growth rings, the [phloem and xylem](http://blogs.evergreen.edu/pim-kosann28/xylem-and-phloem-a-plants-source-and-sink/). If it were burned, another plant could eventually turn the $\ce{CO2}$, $\ce{H2O}$ and minerals back to cellulose and lignin, but *it would no longer be the same piece of wood.*

So this question is one of philosophy, more than of chemistry. As [Plutarch (and others) have asked](https://open.library.okstate.edu/introphilosophy/chapter/ship-of-theseus/), if one were to replace every part of a ship, one at a time, would the resulting vessel be the same as the original? And in an [ancient Buddhist text](https://www.academia.edu/45108237/The_Curious_Case_of_the_Conscious_Corpse_A_Medieval_Buddhist_Thought_Experiment), and in modern [science fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_transplant), the question arises if we're the same person with parts replaced: blood transfusion? cornea replacement? kidney transplant? [brain tissue transplant](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK232006/)?

Comment: It's good that you start with a functional definition. For the definition of reversible to apply it suffices to say that the initial and final properties of the sample are identical (to within measurable precision). If it's thermodynamic reversibility, then thermodynamic properties such as S, H, etc... then the precise position of the atoms is of little importance provided the macroscopic property is retained (see also orthocresols comment under the other answer).

Comment: A good and very sad real example as alternative to destroying Picasso's Guernica: https://www.theguardian.com/artanddesign/2020/jun/22/experts-call-for-regulation-after-latest-botched-art-restoration-in-spain  did the entropy increase or decrease here?